Json schema for enumeration with Draft 2020-12
I have a JSON schema I was using to specify enumerations that map unique string names to unique numbers.
Here is the schema, and yes I am aware that it doesn't guarantee the above requirement, but I'm not bothered about that at the moment.
{
"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
"title": "Module",
"description": "Schema for module definitions",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
    "enums": {
        "type": "object",
        "patternProperties": {
            "^.[^.\"]*$": {
                "$ref": "#/$defs/enum"
            }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
},
"additionalProperties": false,
"$defs": {
    "enum": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": [
                {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            ],
            "minItems": 2,
            "maxItems": 2
        }
    }
}
}

I am converting from Json.net to System.Text.Json & Jsonschema.net.  Here is example JSON object that validated with json.net, but not with Jsonschema.net, presumably because "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema" is taken more seriously with the latter.
{
"enums": {
    "Drive Types": [
        [
            "DOL", 1
        ],
        [
            "VSD", 2
        ],
        [
            "Servo", 3
        ]
    ],
    "Conveyor State": [
        [
            "Off", 0
        ],
        [
            "Faulted", 1
        ],
        [
            "Idle", 2
        ]
    ]
}
}

What I want to do is modify my schema (and JSON object) so that it works with strict validation against Draft 2020-12.  How can I do that?

In 2020-12, items no longer has an array form. That has been replaced with prefixItems. Your schema can replace the inner 2-element array items keyword with prefixItems and that should be correct.
See: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#name-keywords-for-applying-subschema
and https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array

This worked.  For extra detail, this is the relevant modification:
"prefixItems": [
{
"type": "string"
},
{
"type": "integer"
}
]

Seems like you want a schema like this
No need for minItems and maxItems when you define the prefixItems schema. You prevent any additional items by setting items: false
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "Module",
    "description": "Schema for module definitions",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "enums": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^.[^.\"]*$": {
                    "$ref": "#/$defs/enum"
                }
            },
            "unevaluatedProperties": false
        }
    },
    "unevaluatedProperties": false,
    "$defs": {
        "enum": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "array",
                "prefixItems": [
                    {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                ],
                "items": false
            }
        }
    }
}


This doesn't remove the need for minItems - prefixItems does not require that corresponding array elements are present.

You're right, it doesn't require anything, per se.

i missed the inner array on my validation result when referencing minItems. It should be  key: [[]] and then the validation fails for the minimum constraint.  I would still argue using a constraint of minItems: 1 is not the correct constraint because the OP wants to map values and only constraining the schema to minItems: 1 doesn't produce the result they are looking for.  They want two entries on the inner array, the mapping key and the mapping value. If anything, minItems: 2 would make both entries required.  Still no need for maxItems

I agree items: false is at least as good a constraint as maxItems: 2 to limit the array length. I don't follow what you are saying about minItems though, nobody suggested minItems: 1. minItems: 2, as the original schema has, is the way to ensure both prefixItems are present.
